# Programmatically getting Crash Reports inside an iOS app 

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I want to access the crash reports of my app inside my app and i need to send the crash reports to a server. I searched in google and I couldn't find any API that helps my purpose but I found there are open source projects like QuincyKit, plcrashreporter for getting the crash reports of the application. If I use these APIs  will apple reject my app ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no API from Apple to do that. So the only chance is to use a 3rd party framework which catches the crash when it happens and provides options to further process it afterwords.

There are multiple solutions available, one is QuincyKit. The second part of the answer of [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100) shows all known solutions and services that you can use.

Note: I am the developer of QuincyKit and also part of the HockeyApp team.

Answer (score 0):

About QuincyKit:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WYeQT.png]

I've used only Flurry, which has crash collection, and there seems to be no problem in using these libraries in your project for the app store.