# how to get iPhone App Crash Log file from iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, crash-log

Is there a way  to access iphone crash log file via programmatically. I trying to write a crash report feature that when you launch the app after a crash, it will offer to send the crash report to the server. I can't find how to get the crash log within the app.

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers to a similar question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737701/get-previous-run-crash-logs-on-iphone?rq=1

Comment: check this one,may it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715127/programmatically-getting-crash-reports-inside-an-ios-app

Comment: @Christian thanks.actually i am  making my own debugger library so dont want use other library or framework to do that so i check .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following logic for the same.

```
aslmsg q, m;
int i;
const char *key, *val;
float how_old = fTime ;
q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, strLoggerLevel ,ASL_QUERY_OP_LESS_EQUAL);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_FACILITY, [@"YourBundleIdOfAPP" UTF8String] ,ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);

asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_TIME, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - how_old] UTF8String], ASL_QUERY_OP_GREATER_EQUAL);
int goInside=0;
aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);
while (NULL != (m = aslresponse_next(r)))
{
    NSString *cValueToWrite;
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(m, i))); i++)
    {
        //get the only required fields
        if(i==12 || i==10 || i==11 || i==8 || i==9 ||i==3)
        {
            NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];
            val = asl_get(m, key);

            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
            [tmpDict setObject:string forKey:keyString];
        }
    }

    cValueToWrite=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"\n--------------[Debug]----------------\nDateTime: %@\nApplication: %@\nInfo: %@",[tmpDict valueForKey:@"CFLog Local Time"],[tmpDict valueForKey:@"Sender"],[tmpDict valueForKey:@"Message"]];
}
```

`strLoggerLevel` is the `NSString` which holds the logger type which you want which ranges upto 7.

Comment: can you please tell me what to use in place of fTime in your given solution and i m implementing this can it will solve my purpose?

Comment: Its a float value which shows the time in seconds. Means u want log before 1 hr then use 3600.0

Comment: ok.thanks...so i can put Debugging(level Name) in place of  strLoggerLevel for getting crash logs?

Comment: i tried this code with debugger level ASL_STRING_DEBUG and how_old = 3600.0 but i am getting this output:logFile: 
--------------[Debug]----------------
DateTime: (null)
Application: (null)
Info: (null)     Is It working code to get crash logs.?

Comment: Yes yaar its working fine for me. I have created the library using same code. try to print tmpDict. what it will give. Have you replaced the @"YourBundleIdOfAPP"??

Comment: yes friend i replaced .ok i check once again and tell you.

Comment: do one thing also check whether it is going into the if loop or not??

Comment: what happened? Have you checked?

Comment: yes it's going on loop but in log i am getting  this output:- DateTime: (null) Application: (null) Info: (null)

Comment: thanks friend its giving me the logs of app and working fine but my work is to get  crash logs file of when app crashed last time.

Comment: I know. But for that better choice is we ask user who faced the crash issue to send that file of logger in which we logged the crash data. Try with the warning or error which will give you the exact log. also give user facility like drop down for Time and logger level. so that user can send u log of before 1 or 2 or 3 hrs.