# Get crash report from app in ios

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have create ios app. Now I want to get crash report from app, which means if user click a button then need to send a crash report of the app to particular mail id.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can Prefer this Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22654089/3800154

Comment: @MayankPatel I'm trying to use that code, but I'm getting bad access error at this line "asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, strLoggerLevel ,ASL_QUERY_OP_LESS_EQUAL);"... I need to know how to declare "strLoggerLevel" here...