# Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, crash

In very rare occasions, but very persistently some of our users will get a crash in our app. It starts ok but short after it crashes when they pick something from a menu. Those that see it always get it, everybody else works fine. Can someone see something that can help me track it down?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31495848 __kill + 8
1   MYApp                           0x0007a8b6 TFHandleExceptions + 986
2   CoreFoundation                  0x372df950 __handleUncaughtException + 68
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34fe433e _objc_terminate + 122
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36a173be safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 70
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36a1744a std::terminate() + 14
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36a1881e __cxa_rethrow + 82
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34fe42a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
8   CoreFoundation                  0x37235506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
9   CoreFoundation                  0x37235366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
10  GraphicsServices                0x339f4432 GSEventRunModal + 130
11  UIKit                           0x30fe1cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
12  MYApp                           0x0005bc9c main (main.m:17)
13  MYApp                           0x0005bc30 start + 32
```

Comment: TFHandleExceptions -> Testflight exception. Try remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Your app crashes because of an exception. TF doesn't seem to cover these and doesn't show the origin of the crash. The exceptions gets rethrown into the main thread in the next runloop, so the stack trace of the main thread does not show the origin of it. You need to use another crash reporting library which is able to show that information or try to get the original crash report that iOS writes. (Most PLCrashReporter based crash reporting libraries or services can do that)

The reason could be any kind of exception, like NSArray indexOutOfBounds or anything else.

Comment: So actually it's bad to have TestFlight in this case? 1. I don't get the crash report via TestFlight and 2. The crash log doesn't help me either. Any suggestions/links? Can I combine the reporting libraries with TestFlight?

Comment: There are other solutions out there, as mentioned. The 2nd part of the following answer of mine mentions some of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100 (Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the QuincyKit and HockeyApp solutions)