# I can not get a crash report in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-reports, crash-log

I raised the App on the App Store.
I've check in iTunes Connect, crash reports do not accumulate.

Currently using Xcode 4.4 and the App name CityOfOz.

I wonder~T.T.

Other tasks necessary to use crash reports?
How to accumulate based on the crash logs?

I will wait your kind response.

Answer (score 8):

iTunes connect only shows crash reports after a specific group reached a threshold (the amount of crashes needed for that is unknown). Also the list can only be updated once a day. In addition it only shows crash reports if the user did allow to send anonymous data to be send to Apple when setting up the device. Most users don't allow that, hence you don't see any reports. Also before iOS 5.0 these reports would only be send to Apple when the device is synced with iTunes.

I listed some alternatives on how to get crash reports fast and reliably as part of the following answer: [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kemi, the crash reports section in iTunes Connect isn't particularly useful. These days most developers use a third party crash report tool.

In my experience, crashlytics (http://try.crashlytics.com) is one of the best solutions.