# Does apple support setting up a symbol server to analyze iOS Crash Dumps

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

Just like MS's symbol server, does apple support setting up a symbol server to analyze iOS Crash Dumps instead of having to symbolicate crash on the compiling machine?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such server from Apple.

There are multiple third party services which offer server side symbolication of crash reports. I listed some in the second part of this answer: [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100)

All of these services require you to integrate an SDK to collect the crash reports, some do support manual uploading of crash reports too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no server component, but Xcode has commandline tools that allow you to symbolicate crash logs. To do this you need the binary and the dSym file that is created at the same time. It doesn't need to be on the compile machine.