# Generating crash reports on Cocoa Touch apps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, crash-reports

That probably sounds a lot worse than it is, but here's my question.

I am dealing with a crash on an actual device, that one of my tester's is using. At the moment, there is no way to discover what is causing the crash. I can not reproduce it on the simulator. However, on the simulator when something crashes I get log info about it in the output window. But I don't want to keep testing with the device connected.

Is it possible to log crash exceptions, etc into a file when things crash. I know certain apps can do it, but I am not sure how?

Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally two ways to do that:

1. Someone get the tester to send you the crash reports, that iOS created on the device. This is usually too tricky for end users, so the next suggestion works better. That's also why I am not describing how to do that :) But you'll find plenty of documentations on that process.
2. Integrate a crash reporting library, that catches the crashes and allows you to receive them in various ways. You should not implement your own global crash exception handler, things are just too complex to do it right (even though other people will tell you otherwise). Also crashes caused by exceptions are only one type of crashes.

   There are multiple open source libraries out there, the safest one to use is anything based on PLCrashReporter. Most others use private or undocumented iOS APIs, or are not async-safe, which basically means those can destroy app data or make the crash even worse. See this blog post about the topic: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/crashreporting/Reliable_Crash_Reporting_1.1.20130119.html

   The following linked answer shows some of the available options on how to add logging to your app and also various options on how to receive crash reports for test version and also once the app is released: [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100)

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third party service, I use https://www.crashlytics.com. Makes debugging crashes from user devices painless.